# Why do we need a proxy to download public and private modules in NPM?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

Let's say I have a private npm repo, http://private.com/npm-internal

how come I would need a proxy to allow me to install modules from both public and private repos? I would love a more in-depth explanation, as I'm not incredibly familiar with npm.

Comment: Your deployment target needs access to some network that has access to internal private repo's.

Comment: This is because otherwise, the world would be able to access it.